# MS Access 2003 - Good book on learning advanced VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

Hey guys! Was wondering is anyone had any suggestions on books or other resources on learning novice to advanced VBA as it relates to access programming. I have bought and read the "Access Bible", "The only access book you'll ever need", and "Sams TY in 21Days" and they were all fine for learning the basics.

Then I bought and read teh O'Rielly Programming book and thought it was great (a little more gratifying, and I learned a lot more with this book rather than the others). So I am kinda looking for something more alnog the line of this one...the more examples the better.

Appreciate the advise; thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you asked specifically about books, I'll suggest O'Reilly's [Access Cookbook](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596006785/).  I found that one useful for an intermediate level approach to Access VBA.

Other than books, the biggest gain for me has been participating in the microsoft.public.access newsgroups.  It gives me an opportunity to study the approaches of many real Access experts.  And when I reply to questions I get to benefit from their review.

Comment: Another great resource is the Access group at www.databaseadvisors.com

Comment: hey thanks! I will certainly check this out...i would say i am still a novice but i am definately looking to learn more! thanks man!

Answer (score 5):

[Access Developer's Handbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0782140114) was the best by far.

[VBA Developer's Handbook, 2nd Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0782129781) is also excellent.

Comment: Agreed.  While they won't have the A2007 specific features in them these books are exceedingly valid for advanced Access topics.   The reality is that A2007 is focussed more on the GUi and Sharepoint than VBA and developer topics anyhow.  (In addition to the A2002 volumes I also have the A97 and A2000 versions.)

Comment: ADH is the best Access book bar none.

Comment: thanks very much...i will definately get it!

Answer (score 1):

I was quite satisfied with Access 2003 VBA Programmer's Reference [here is a link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470047038) to the 2007 version.

Comment: thanks! i think i will give that one a shot!