# Populating MS Access form from ComboBox selection(variable number of rows to populate)

Tags: database, ms-access, vba

Here's the general schema for my tables(incomplete)

```
   Employees(**EMPiD**, FirstName, Lastname, cell, name)

   Trainers(**TrainerName**, Specialty)

   EmployeeTrainingCompleted(**EMPID,TypeTraining,** TrainerName, Score, Comments)

   Training(**TypeTraining,PositionTitle**) //this one is fishy, and likely subject to change, but irrelevent to this question

   Position(**PositionTitle**,Description,StartingPay)
```

I am working on an Access 2010 form that will allow the user to select from a combobox the "name" field of a particular employee(which is a calculated field from fname,lname) and view all of the completed training, trainer name, comments, score, etc for that EMPID.

I have completed forms that do this for a single instance of training, but I would like for there to be one form that will dynamically display an indeterminate amount of rows for each employee(because employees have completed a different amount of training courses).

I am new to Microsoft Access and I was wondering if there is an easy way to accomplish this.

Thanks for your input.

Comment: I have not. I'm new to access, my only experience is from a book I got and online resources.. I've been getting by by drawing my knowledge of MySQL and oracle databases. Are subforms something that would be useful for this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While MySQL and Oracle are useful for the database side of things, they will be of no use for the RAD side. Access is really a RAD tool that generally, but by no means always, uses a Jet/ACE database for a back-end ( https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ms-access/info ).

To get a general idea of what you can do with Access, look at the Northwind Sample database, which you will find in New --> Sample Templates --> Northwind in your Access 2010 or if you intend to work with a web deployment, http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-access/archive/2010/07/19/northwind-2010-web-database-is-now-available.aspx.

Calling these "databases" is misleading, in that they include a great deal more than you will find in a database. In this case, have a look at the Order Details form under Customers & Orders.

I am not sure about the 2010 version of Northwind, but the earlier versions used to come with a warning that you should disregard any code and just use them for ideas on what you can do with MS Access. For code, consider these books [MS Access 2003 - Good book on learning advanced VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457865/ms-access-2003-good-book-on-learning-advanced-vba).

Comment: Thanks for the information. I am starting to enjoy a lot of the extra functionality that access provides(It's nice to not have to build an application from scratch), I just need to work with it some more to get familiar. Also, after I'm done building this system, I need to separate the interface from the data completely(I don't want people to directly manipulate the data, the only changes I want are possible from the forms that I will create). I'm sure access supports this, right?

Comment: It is recommended that you split the database into a backend and frontend, one to keep forms etc, one for data. It is often wise to do this fairly early on, because I have found that forms are more easily corrupted during development in an unsplit database. You should also keep regular back-ups, and I mean *very* regular, and decompile often during development. You will not get the same level of security with an Access backend that you will get with, say, SQL Server, but if you have maliciously inclined employees working on your server, you are in trouble any way.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help. I saw that feature to "split" it and I was curious about it. I was planning on splitting it after I've completed all the forms, macros(like triggers?), and queries. Just to be clear, you are recommending to do this before I finish the development of this system?